# Trouble sorting an array of objects

Tags: java

Question is as follows:
Write a program named SortSalon that contains an array to hold six HairSalon objects and fill it  with data.  Include a method to sort the array in ascending order by price of service.  Call the method and display the results.

```
public class SortSalon
{
    private static HairSalon [] itsArray = new HairSalon[6];

    public SortSalon()
    {
        itsArray[0] = new HairSalon("cut", 10.50, 15);
        itsArray[1] = new HairSalon("shampoo", 5.00, 10);
        itsArray[2] = new HairSalon("manicure", 20.00, 20);
        itsArray[3] = new HairSalon("cut", 10.50, 15);
        itsArray[4] = new HairSalon("manicure", 20.00, 20);
        itsArray[5] = new HairSalon("manicure", 20.00, 20);
    }

    public HairSalon [] sortByPrice(HairSalon [] par)
    {
        HairSalon [] newArray = new HairSalon[6];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        HairSalon smallest = itsArray[1];

        for(int i = 0; i < itsArray.length; i++)
        {
            while(y < itsArray.length - 1)
            {
                if(itsArray[y].getPrice() == smallest.getPrice())
                {
                    smallest = itsArray[y];
                    newArray[x] = smallest;
                }
                else
                {
                    //smallest = itsArray[y];
                    for(int c = 0; c < itsArray.length - 1; c++)
                    {
                        if(itsArray[y].getPrice() < itsArray[y + 1].getPrice() 
                        && itsArray[y].getPrice() >  smallest.getPrice())
                        {
                            smallest = itsArray[y];
                            newArray[x] = smallest;
                        }
                    }
                }
                y++;
            }
            y = 0;
            //newArray[x] = smallest;
            x++;
        }

        int z = 0;
        System.out.println("Ascending order: ");

        while(z < newArray.length)
        {
            System.out.println(newArray[z].toString());
            z++;
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        SortSalon test = new SortSalon();
        test.sortByPrice(itsArray);
    }
}
```

Can't get the method to correctly sort the objects by price. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

The problem here is the logic of sorting, not really a coding issue. If you can figure out in pseudo-code how to arrange the array according to price, you can figure out the code.

I don't think we are supposed to help with homework, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Java's in-built sorting methods, or do you have to write your own algorithm?

Comment: @RoyWasse in the `HairSalon` class, obviously.  Which, by the way, is a terrible name for a class that represents one service offered by a Salon.

Comment: We are allowed to use built-in methods. This is not homework it is for an online class that I am taking, independent from school. I just can't figure out the logic, much less how to implement it efficiently.

Comment: In that case, you need to write a `Comparator`, to compare two `HairSalon` objects (did I mention that `HairSalon` is a terrible name for this class?)  and then use `Arrays.sort`.  A good first step for you would be to read up on how to write a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way (using already defined sorting algoritms is using the interface "Comparable", for Example:

```
private class HairSalon implements Comparable<HairSalon>{
    public String type = null;
    public double price = 0;
    public float number = 0;

    public HairSalon(String type,double price,float number){
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HairSalon compa) {
        int ret = 0;
        if(this.price < compa.price) ret = -1;

        if(this.price > compa.price){
            ret = 1;
        }else{ret = 0;}

        return ret;
    }
```

}

Then you can use the Collections sorting algorithms:

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<HairSalon>(Arrays.asList(itsArray)));
```

But iof you are having trouble with an specific implementation of any sorting mechanism this wouldn't help.

Comment: I don't really like this.  It suggests that "by price" is the most natural way to sort `HairSalon` objects.  As soon as you want to sort by something different, you have to use a different technique.  It would make far more sense to use a `Comparator` for this - then you can later implement a `Comparator` for sorting by type and a `Comparator` for sorting by number, if those end up being required.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your HairSalon objects with `Comparator`, you can define your custom comparison way, and using `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` for your sorting

You can either choose `Comparable` or `Comparator` for your sorting. I prefer using `Comparator`, the reason is the comparison logic is in a separated class. That means you dont need to modify your `HairSalon` class, and you can have multiple self-defined Comparators class for different fields comparison/sorting.

Sample:

```
public class HairSalon {
    private final String type;
    private final double price;

    public HairSalon(String type, double price){
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getType(){ return this.type;}
    public double getPrice(){return this.price;}
}


public class PriceComparator implements Comparator<HairSalon> {

/**
 *comparison/sorting logic is here
 */
@Override
public int compare(HairSalon hs1, HairSalon hs2)
{
    if(hs1.getPrice() > hs2.getPrice()){return 1;}
    else if(hs1.getPrice() == hs2.getPrice()){return 0;}
    else{return -1;}
}
```

}

How you sort them:

```
    //if you put all your HairSalon objects in an array:
    Arrays.sort(hairSalonsArray, new PriceComparator())    

    //if you put all your HairSalon in a list
    Collections.sort(hairSalonsList, new PriceComparator());
```

Comment: if you explain comparable vs comparator I would gladly vote you up

Comment: I'm haven't used this approach yet, but I will look into it and see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: @KickButtowski the best part I prefer Comparator is we can write our own custom XXXComparator without modify the original HairSalon class, we can define the comparison logic in the XXXComparator clas

Comment: @haifzhan add this explanation to your post plz

Comment: @Jacob please see the example provided

Comment: @Jacob great to know that! Seems like you chose Comparable as your answer:)